# ManyToMany and mappedBy error Unknown column

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I try to create a `ManyToMany` relation with one extra column (`OrderItem.quantity`). So I use following entities:
**Orders table:**

```
@Entity(name = "EshopOrder")
@Table(name="eshop_order")
public class EshopOrder implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_order")
    private int idOrder;
    
    @Column(name="date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;
    
    @Column(name="total")
    private float total;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_customer")
    private Customer customer;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)   
    private List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
    
    public EshopOrder() {
        
    }
    ... getters, etc.
}
```

**"Join table":**

```
@Entity(name = "OrderItem")
@Table(name="order_item")
public class OrderItem {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderItemId id;
    
    @Column(name="quantity")
    private Integer quantity;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("idOrder")
    private EshopOrder order;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("idProduct")
    private Product product;
    
    public OrderItem() {
    }
    
    public OrderItem(EshopOrder order, Product product, Integer quantity) {
        this.order = order;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.id = new OrderItemId(order.getIdOrder(), product.getIdProduct());
    }
    ... getters, etc.   
}
```

**Product(s) which are order items:**

```
@Entity(name="product")
@Table(name="product")
@NaturalIdCache
@Cache(
    usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE
)
public class Product implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_product")
    private int idProduct;
    
    @Column(name="id_category")
    private int idCategory;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_category", insertable=false, updatable =false)
    private Category category;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="availability")
    private int availability;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "order",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
            )     
    private List<OrderItem> orders = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

    @Column(name="price")
    private float price;
    
    public Product() {
        
    }

    public Product(int idProduct, int idCategory, String name, String description, int availability, float price) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
        this.idCategory = idCategory;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.availability = availability;
        this.price = price;
    }
    ...getters, etc
}
```

And finally, in order to model the `quantity` column I use **this** extra **class**:

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderItemId implements Serializable{
    
    @Column(name = "id_order")
    private int idOrder;
    
    @Column(name = "id_product")
    private int idProduct;
    
    public OrderItemId() {
        
    }
    
    public OrderItemId(int idOrder, int idProduct) {
        this.idOrder = idOrder;
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }
    ... getters, etc.
}
```

When I try to view items of a order it keeps giving me this exception:
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'items0_.product_id_product' in 'field list'`. This error looks kinda understandable, there really is no column named `product_id_product`. Which leads me to idea like *it* forgot to add a dot operator (`items0_.product.id_product`) which would make totally sense and should work. *Do you know what happened? Can you see what is wrong with it?*

EDIT (SQL scripts to create database):

```
CREATE TABLE `product`(
`id_product` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`availability` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price` float(10,2) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE `eshop_order`(
`id_order` int (11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`date_created` date NOT NULL,
`id_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
`total` float(10,2) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE `order_item`(
`id_order` int (11) NOT NULL,
`id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
`quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL)
```

These are just snippets in order to show the DB background (column names).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `mappedBy`on the `items` field in the `EshopOrder` class:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class EshopOrder implements Serializable{
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)   
    private List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

}
```

You have a 1:N relationship from `EshopOrder` to `OrderItem` and the field which is used for managing this relationship of `EshopOrder` and `OrderItem` can't be the `product` field in the `OrderItem` class because it is a `Product` and not `EshopOrder`.

The same applies to `Product`, you specify in your code that there is a field called `order` in the `OrderItem` entity that reference the parent side of the 1:N relationship `Product`. It should however be `product`:

```java
@Entity
@Table
@NaturalIdCache
@Cache(
    usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE
)
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "product",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
            )     
    private List<OrderItem> orders = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

}
```

If you haven't fully understood mapping relationships with JPA, I recommend that you study [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) by Hibernate maintainer Vlad Mihalcea on how to map `@OneToMany` relationships most efficiently. He has also excellent articles on how to best map `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToMany` relationships.

The rest of your `@MapsId` logic looks good to me, it looks exactly like [the example in the documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/static/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax/persistence/MapsId.html). You can also check if your error results from the mismatch of `@MapsId("idOrder")` -> `@Column(name = "id_order")` repectively `@MapsId("idProduct")` -> `@Column(name = "id_product")`. Have you tried harmonizing the column names?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it doesn't seem to work. I switched `mappedBy` content and still getting similar error: `Unknown column 'items0_.order_id_order' in 'field list'`. I can't see what's wrong here. Isn't it weird that Spring thinks there should be a `order_id_order` named column? I'm trying to figure out where does this information come from (and of course what's wrong with my code).

Comment: And the article you attached is fine but doesn't meet my need because it deals only with pure ManyToMany relation (no extra column).

Comment: @user7303261 I had another idea and edited my post, check it out. The article is totally applicable to your situation because you have two `@OneToMany` which you mapped incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Parameter of `@MapsId` is the name of one of the attributes from the `@Embeddable` class. Can't see what I could possibly mismatch. I will edit the question and add the snippet of the database design. Damn I can't see what's wrong with that...

Comment: @user7303261 `idOrder` is not equal to `id_order`, that's what I meant

Comment: Parameter of `@MapsId` is the name of one of the attributes from the `@Embeddable` class. - Isn't it?

Comment: There is OrderItemId.idOrder, that's why I use later as `@MapsId("idOrder")`.